# Passing a tab character as a command line argument in Java

Tags: java, bash

So, basically, I want to successfully pass an arbitrary string in java that could contain special characters (such as tabs). Here's this code sample:

```
String tab = "\t"; 
//String tab = args[0];
String full = "hi"+tab+"hi"+tab+"bye";
String[] parts = full.split(tab);
String print = "";
for (String s : parts) {
    print += s + tab;
}
print = print.substring(0, print.length()-tab.length());
System.out.println(print);
```

Split successfully recovers the parts regardless of how the variable tab is defined. However, when it's actually printed, defining tab manually (the non-commented out version) prints it as expected, with tab characters. However, passing through command line causes it to actually print "\t" (the same as if the String was actually "\\t" for instance).

I'm primarily using bash, and would be happy for any bash-specific ideas, though would be happier if it also included a general explanation of what's happening. Why is the regex of both the same while the String literal is different?

bash invocation of the program:

```
ARGS="$X $Y $Z \t"

java -cp $CLASSPATH $MEM $PROGRAM $ARGS 2> "${PROGRAM##*.}-error.log" > "${PROGRAM##*.}-out.log"
```

The answer provided here does actually mostly work for my purposes, is fairly readable, and generally only fails on fairly unusual things: "\\\t", for instance:  https://gist.github.com/uklimaschewski/6741769

Comment: I dont get your question. You want that your java code calls another program and passes "real" tabs to that?

Comment: maybe you should post how you executed this java code in bash

Comment: @bhaal can you add a sample invocation from the command line that you use?

Comment: ok, I added the actual invocation.

Comment: This isn't even vaguely a duplicate of the indicated question.

Comment: I flagged this as the marked "duplicate" isn't a duplicate at all

Answer (score 7):

The `tab` that you defined in code is a single-character string (since "\t" is an [escape sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)).
From the command line you get a two-characters string, as bash doesn't handle "\t" as the tab character.

To pass that from command line, you can use `echo -e` which supports escape sequences like `\t` (or `\n` and a few others):

```
$ java Main "$(echo -en '\t')"
```

Comment: In Bash, you can do that more elegantly with C-string syntax; `java Main $"\t"`

Comment: java did not seem to capture the argument for the one in the answer. For the second, java captures the bash argument as a string literal

Answer (score 4):

The simplest by far is:

```
java my.package.Main $'\t'
```

Comment: this actually passes that as a string literal, and doesn't split correctly

Comment: @bhaall
`$ echo -n $'\t' | od -x`
`0000000 0009`

Comment: This works for me from the command line

Answer (score 2):

If you pass `'\t'` or `"\t"` on your command line, it causes a literal backslash followed by a `t` to be passed to your command:

```
$ echo -n '\t' | xxd
00000000: 5c74                                     \t

$ echo -n "\t" | xxd
00000000: 5c74                                     \t
```

You can type a tab on your command line using <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
$ echo -n '     ' | xxd
00000000: 09                                       .
```

(That wide space is a tab character, not lots of spaces).

Comment: I tried typing a literal tab, and java didn't seem to capture it as an argument. I'm maybe not entirely sure what you're suggesting

Answer (score 2):

To pass a tab as an argument from bash, you can do any of the following:

`mycommand $'arg\tcontaining\ttabs'`
Which works because `$''` in bash interprets escape sequences.

`mycommand 'arg`<kbd>ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>`containing`<kbd>ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>`tabs'`
Which works because <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd> causes the next character typed to be inserted literally rather than being interpreted.

`mycommand "$(printf 'arg\tcontaining\ttabs')"`
Which works, in bash and other shells, because `printf` interprets backslash-escaped characters in its first argument.

Comment: I tried that, but java captured it as a string literal and did not split on it correctly

Comment: Are you certain you are using `bash` and not something like `dash`? Did the `printf` version work for you?